# What are some OOoBasic best practices?

Tags: macros, openoffice.org

What are some best practices for programming a OOoBasic program?

So far I know you should use [XRay](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Extensions_development_basic#X-Ray_tool) but there are an awful lot of weird little quirks in there as well.

Comment: @Google: No results found for "best practices for programming a StarBasic program". :)

Comment: @Robert...it's kinda of a sucky language...but I still wanna know.

Comment: First rule of Starbasic is we don't talk about Starbasic

Comment: How I can I lose points for this?  I program in other languages too..this is seriously a valid question.  You can't doc a guy just because he asks a question about a crappy language.  

Not all of us have the "luxury" of programming in a language of our choosing, that's beyond my control.  

But I just wondered if anyone knew of ways of making working with it better.

Comment: I suppose a question about Fortran would get downvoted into nothingness ...

Comment: @Adrien Nope, there's 62 Fortran questions on this site!

Comment: @leeand00 - Ahh ... so "Ugly and old" is okay, but "ugly and new" isn't ... Interesting how we've broken some stereotypes.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install the [XRay](http://ooomacros.sourceforge.net/dev.php#101416) inspection tool.  It's a must-have (imo) for developing in OOoBasic

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find [this](http://www.pitonyak.org/AndrewMacro.sxw). It is Useful Macro Information for OpenOffice.org by Andrew Pitonyak, it is a over 500 page .odt file that you may find useful.

[Updated documentation](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://tinyurl.com/lsb5ed)

Or go [there](http://documentation.openoffice.org/manuals/oooauthors/macros_intro_v1.pdf) (macros_intro_v1.pdf)

Comment: Non-tinyurl links with descriptions other than this and there would be nicer.